# UIAlertViewDelegate:clickedButtonAtIndex and two buttons

Tags: ios, uialertview

guys:

There is two buttons in my viewController of test app, the right one I call it "NO",

and the other one is "YES". The two buttons will call two different functions, and when

user press one of the buttons , I want show the user an alert to  confirm that.

I know use the UIAlertViewDelegate

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

but there is two buttons, I am puzzled. How can I know which button is pressed.

So,pls help me with this, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you create an `UIAlertView` you can set up a `tag` for it

```
-(IBAction)yesButtonClick:(id)sender{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    alert.tag = 101;
    [alert show];
}

-(IBAction)noButtonClick:(id)sender{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    alert.tag = 102;
    [alert show];
}
```

In the delegate method check which alert is being shown

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == 101) {
        // from YES button
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == 102) {
        // from NO button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet
    clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
  switch(buttonIndex){
    case 0:
      //YES button handler
      break;
    case 1:
      //NO button handler
      break;
    default:
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: @beryllium: yes even me thinks the same

Comment: Yeah,I want to know is the "YES"button or "NO"button pressed, and then make sure the user want to go on, thanks for your replies!

Comment: What are u talking about? Do you want to determine what button did pressed? If it's so, here's code. If i get it right, you have only 1 alert view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the tag attribute to make the difference between your tow UIAlertView
in the  function of button 1
`alertView1.tag=1;`
and in

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(actionSheet.tag==1){
//first button was clicked
}

}
```